# Python - Use column name with int and string

Tags: python

I have imported an NBA statistical dataset. But some of my column names have 2 data types, as in "3PP" or "2FG". Therefore, the following code won't work.

```
for team in nba.3PP
```

Because when it runs, it gives an "invalid syntax" error. Is there a special way I can use 3PP like .\3PP or something to get it to work? Thanks!

EDIT: Using Pandas dataFrame

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you've imported into. If Pandas:

```
for team in nba['3PP']:
   ...
```

This uses the item-oriented indexing, rather than attribute-oriented indexing. In Python in general, they are not equivalent, but in Pandas they can often be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.get` method:

```
nba.get("3PP")
```

Or:

```
nba['3PP']
```

Depending on if the dataset is in Pandas or whatnot.